# What does a linear transformation do to a vector in $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: linear-algebra, rotations

$\newcommand{\Reals}{\mathbb{R}}$Doing some linear algebra. This question has me intrigued. I imagine it causes the vector to rotates the $x$ axis. But I mean, is there more to it? 
$$
T_{A(\theta)}: \Reals^2 \to \Reals^2,\qquad
A(\theta) = 
\left[\begin{array}
{rr}\cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\  
\sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
\end{array}\right].
$$
What, geometrically, does the linear transformation $T_{A(\theta)}$
do to a vector in $\Reals^2$?

Comment: This is the rotation matrix

Comment: so the rotation matrix, will rotate the vector anticlockwise about the x-axis if i'm reading correctly?

Comment: try to input vectors (base vectors) and see what happens.

Comment: ah so rather it just rotates it in {R}^2 in general not necessarily x

Comment: Did the school actually say the words "What does the transformation do to a vector"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take the standard basis vector of  $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ and then draw it on the $X$ and $Y$ axis as an arrow vector. Now find the image of $A_\theta (1, 0)$ and $A_\theta (0, 1)$ for different values of $\theta$ and plot them again. You may see how $A_\theta$ rotates these vectors by an angle $\theta$.

To get further insight draw a rectangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with vertices $(0, 0)$, $(1, 0)$ $(1, 1)$ $(0, 1)$. Now find image of each of these vectors by assuming a particular values of $\theta$. Now analyze how the rectangle is rotated by an angle $\theta$ by rotation matrix $A_{\theta}$.

If you want to see the real life application of rotation matrix in Robotics and robot control follow [this link](https://studywolf.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/robot-control-forward-transformation-matrices/).